# PHP/Python Replace first string in a line with another string

Tags: php, python, regex, string, output

I'm trying to replace the first ":" with "space" and I don't have a clue on how to do it!
Maybe you guys can help me.

In a text:

```
ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl:mn
12:ab:c2:f3 303:mx:
dk:ad:Y4:D3
12:31:44:aC:210 sda:
```

The output will be :

```
ab cd:ef:gh:ij:kl:mn
12 ab:c2:f3 303:mx:
dk ad:Y4:D3
12 31:44:aC:210 sda:
```

Maybe you could help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are those lines in some file, or as a part of a string? Or are they all different strings?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation of `str_replace()` in PHP? It has everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use in php:

```
$result = preg_replace('~^[^:]*\K:~m', ' ', $text);
```

where:

`[^:]` means *all characters except `:`*

`\K` reset all the match before.

`m` stand for *multiline mode* (the begining anchor `^` means *start of the line* instead of the default *start of the string*)

Answer (score 1):

In python,

```
a = 'ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl:mn'
a = a.replace(':', ' ', 1)
```

yields

```
ab cd:ef:gh:ij:kl:mn
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in should work in PHP:

```
$output = preg_replace("/(^.*?):/m", "$1 ", $input);
```

Will replace the first `:` on each line with a space.

For example:

```
$input = "ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl:mn
12:ab:c2:f3 303:mx:
dk:ad:Y4:D3
12:31:44:aC:210 sda:";
print "<pre>$input</pre>";
print "--------------------";

$output = preg_replace("/(^.*?):/m", "$1 ", $input);

print "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Will output

```
ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl:mn 
12:ab:c2:f3 303:mx: 
dk:ad:Y4:D3 
12:31:44:aC:210 sda:
--------------------
ab cd:ef:gh:ij:kl:mn 
12 ab:c2:f3 303:mx: 
dk ad:Y4:D3 
12 31:44:aC:210 sda:
```